# Getx show bottom sheet after response backend

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I am writing to you for support on Getx.
I currently have a GetView class where there is a button that needs to call a method defined inside the controller.
This method makes a call to a server and then after the call, it must show a BottomSheet.
Unfortunately, and I think this is my limit on GETX, I noticed that the BottomSheet is shown immediately without waiting for the response from the backend.
I tried with the wait but unfortunately without success.
Is there any tutorial I can view?
Thank you all.

Code method controller

```
Future<bool> increaseWallet() async {
    
    try{
      await MangoPay.instance.makePayment(
          mangoPayUserId: user!.mangoPayId!, 
          mangoPayPaymentWalletId: user!.walletId!, 
          cardData: _cardData, amount: double.parse(amount), 
            paymentCallback: (result, message, transactionId, status) async {
            if(status=="SUCCEEDED"){
              hideLoader();
              _bContinue = true;
            }
      });
    }
    catch(e){
      hideLoader();
      return bContinue;
    }
    finally {
      hideLoader();
    }
    return bContinue;
  }
```

Page

```
SizedBox(
                width: double.infinity,
                child: PrimaryButtonBG(
                  text: 'Ricarica wallet',
                  onTap: () {
                    controller.increaseWallet().then((bContinue){
                      openSuccessWallet(context);
                    });
                    
                  },
                ),
              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to wait you should use this Future. delay(Duration(Xyz)) or Timer function

---

```
SizedBox(
            width: double.infinity,
            child: PrimaryButtonBG(
              text: 'Ricarica wallet',
              onTap: () {
                Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: XYZ )),
                controller.increaseWallet().then((bContinue){
                  openSuccessWallet(context);
                });
                
              },
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: No this solution not function

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is using workers, for example:

```
class WalletController extends GetxController {
  final increasedWallet = false.obs; //your control trigger

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();

    //worker that listening status of RxBool trigger
    ever(increasedWallet, (value) {
      if (value == true) {

        ////////
        //place here code for showing bottomSheet
        ////////

        increasedWallet.value = false;
      }
    });
  }
  
  Future<bool> increaseWallet() async {
    try {
      await MangoPay.instance.makePayment(
          mangoPayUserId: user!.mangoPayId!,
          mangoPayPaymentWalletId: user!.walletId!,
          cardData: _cardData,
          amount: double.parse(amount),
          paymentCallback: (result, message, transactionId, status) async {
            if (status == "SUCCEEDED") {
              increasedWallet.value = true; //here trigger turns worker on
              hideLoader();
              _bContinue = true;
            }
          });
      
    } catch (e) {
      hideLoader();
      return bContinue;
    } finally {
      hideLoader();
    }
    return bContinue;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SizedBox(
            width: double.infinity,
            child: PrimaryButtonBG(
              text: 'Ricarica wallet',
              onTap: () async {
               bool? value = await controller.increaseWallet();
                if(value != null){
                   openSuccessWallet(context);
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to update UI with Getx, there are 2 ways:

1. Use Obx wrap Widget need update, then when `"_bContinue = true;"` the UI will update
2. If you don't know where to put Obx, you can wrap your whole page with GetBuilder, but this way you have to update you boolean var, ex:

- In your controller: `void showBottomSheet() { _bContinue = true; update(); }`
- Then call function when `status == 'SUCCEEDED'`